# How to get json value

Tags: php, json

I am using jquery ajax for calling PHP

PHP

```
$response = array('isSuccessful'=> true , 'currentId'=> $currentId);
$response = json_encode($response);
echo $response;
```

Success() in ajax

```
success:function(data){
                var currentData=data;
                console.log(currentData);
                var s=currentData.currentId;
                console.log(s);
            }
```

Output is

```
{"isSuccessful":true,"currentId":13} 
undefined
```

What is the mistake i made.

Comment: Are you also using jQuery? Can you show some more of the call in ajax, please?

Comment: $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"php/registerDetails.php",
   data:data,
   success:function(data){
    var currentData=data;
    console.log(currentData);
    var s=currentData.currentId;
    console.log(s);
   },
   error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(errorThrown);
   },
  });

Comment: `1)` Open the ajax url in browser and make sure it has only json string and no other extra characters. `2)` Use a content-type:json header in php `3)` Specify dataType as json in jquery request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to send the correct headers (which in this case is `application/json`):

```
$response = array('isSuccessful'=> true , 'currentId'=> $currentId);
$response = json_encode($response);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $response;
```

Or if you want to parse it yourselves, then you can use [`$.parseJSON(data)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), but make sure to manage the error thrown if the parsing fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dataType in the ajax call, as can be read [in the ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"php/registerDetails.php",
  data:data,
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(data){
    var currentData=data;
    console.log(currentData);
    var s=currentData.currentId;
    console.log(s);
    },
  error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(errorThrown);
    },
  });
```

This is normally not required (for example, if you set the headers and let jquery guess it), but I'd recommend making sure that jquery knows the data it's receiving and handling the error if any than relying on a script on another page with another language to make sure of your data integrity.